# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3

Tags: makefile, ld, nix

while installing nix I am getting this error.when I doing make.

```
LD    src/libstore/libnixstore.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [src/libstore/libnixstore.so] Error 1
```

I already set LDFLAGS to the directory containing libsqlite3.* and libbz2.*

update:
here is output of make V=1

```
Makefile:28: Makefile.config: No such file or directory
rm -f Makefile.config && ./config.status --quiet --file=Makefile.config
g++ -o /home/kapil/nix/src/nix-1.8/src/libstore/libnixstore.so -shared -Wl,--no-copy-dt-needed-entries src/libstore/build.o src/libstore/derivations.o src/libstore/gc.o src/libstore/globals.o src/libstore/local-store.o src/libstore/misc.o src/libstore/optimise-store.o src/libstore/pathlocks.o src/libstore/references.o src/libstore/remote-store.o src/libstore/store-api.o -lsqlite3 -lbz2 -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-soname=libnixstore.so    -Wl,-rpath,/home/kapil/nix/src/nix-1.8/src/libutil -Lsrc/libutil -lnixutil    -Wl,-rpath,/home/kapil/nix/src/nix-1.8/src/boost/format -Lsrc/boost/format -lnixformat  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [src/libstore/libnixstore.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Run the make with `V=1` or `VERBOSE=1` or whatever appropriate flag it requires and see what command it is actually running there.

Comment: it gives something like this Makefile:28: Makefile.config: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you see your `LDFLAGS` added paths on that `g++` line?

Comment: yes but its just -lsqlite3 -lbz2. not an absolute path

Comment: Um... you said you set `LDFLAGS` to have the directory containing those files. Is that not what you did? Where are those libraries on your system? You shouldn't need to add `-lsqlite3 -lbz2` manually. Either the software uses those libraries and it will list them or it doesn't use them and manually listing them is unlikely to do anything of any use. What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: I am installing nix as per the steps mentioned [here](https://nixos.org/wiki/How_to_install_nix_in_home_%28on_another_distribution%29#Manual_Installation)

Comment: So you run `export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/nix-boot/lib $LDFLAGS"` in your current shell session? Which step is failing now? The `nix` install step itself?

Comment: upto this step  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/nix-boot --with-store-dir=$HOME/nix/store --localstatedir=$HOME/nix/var everything works fine.but when I run make it gives above mentioned error.

Comment: And you ran the full set of steps for sqlite3 and bzip2 listed before that step? You didn't miss running the commands for sqlite3 because the directions only list them once for both curl and sqlite3?

Comment: yeah I already repeated same steps for installing sqlite3,curl,bzip2

Comment: What files do you have in `$HOME/nix-boot/lib`?

Comment: libsqlite3.a,libsqlite.so any much more

Comment: `libsqlite.so`? Not `libsqlite3.so`?

Comment: sorry.its libsqlite3.so

Comment: `LDFLAGS` is either not exported or, despite the instructions, that is the wrong thing to set. Try exporting it again (and confirming it has the value you expect) and then see about finding out what variable/etc. is actually going to affect that compilation line.